# Selecionar automaticamente um select e acionar o botão

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho um campo do tipo `<select>`/`<option>` que quando o usuário seleciona um valor eu chamo uma função para popular um outro `<select>`, tipo os combos de estado e cidade, isso está funcionando, e daí o usuário clica em um botão que faz uma chamada ajax para trazer alguns dados pra exibir.

O que preciso e não estou sabendo é quando tiver nesse meu primeiro `<select>` apenas um valor, já vir selecionado, dai já fazer a chamada para esse segundo `select` e já acionar o botão mesmo sem o usuário selecionar esse segundo select.

Por exemplo, eu tenho um `select` de estado outro de cidade e um botão.
Ao selecionar um estado o usuário já pode acionar o botão ou selecionar alguma cidade e acionar o botão, só que quando tiver apenas um estado já vir selecionado esse estado e também já acionar esse botão, dando apenas ao usuário a opção de selecionar uma cidade e dai acionar o botão.

Espero não ter sido muito confuso e que possam entender para poder me ajudar.

```
<label for="estado">
<select>
    <option value="0"> ---Selecione--- </option>
    <option value="SP"> São Paulo </option>
</select>

<label for="cidade">
<select>
    <option value="0"> ---Selecione--- </option>
</select>

<button type="submit" id="listarItens">Buscar</button>
```

Nesse caso se tiver somente o Estado de São Paulo já selecionar e acionar o botão Buscar, lembrando que eu tenho uma função criada que quando o usuário seleciona o estado chama essa função.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    changeSelect('estado', ['cidade'], 'selecionaCidades.php');

    $('#listarItens').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        //aqui executa algumas coisas como um ajax, mas isso acho que não preciso listar correto
    });


});
```

Não sei se tem necessidade de eu passar toda estrutura dessa função changeSelect certo.

Comment: Pode colocar o código que já tem? mais fácil perceber, e responder...

Comment: Pode usar este exemplo para re-criar o que pretende?: __http://jsfiddle.net/xv9Lg/__

Comment: @Sergio já adicionei um exemplo do que preciso. Espero que ajude e me ajudar.

Comment: Marcelo, todos os selects têm um `<option value="0"> ---Selecione--- </option>` ?

Comment: Tem sim @Sergio

Comment: Ok. Deixei uma resposta em baixo. Era isso que procura?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teste usar assim para saber se um select só tem uma option:

```
$('select').each(function () {
    var options = $(this).find('option');
    var qtdOptions = options.length;
    if (qtdOptions == 2)  {      // uso dois porque a sua primeira option é só uma guia
        this.selectedIndex = 1;  // escolher a segunda option
        $("select[name='estado']").change();
        $('#listarItens').trigger('click');  // carregar no botão!
    }
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/9MWTH/)

Este código procura todos os selects e se algum têm só uma opção (talvez queria usar `==2` uma vez que tem o texto neutral `---Selecione---`). Se não quiser procurar todos os selects o código pode ser mais simples.

Comment: Então, entendi o que mandou, agradeço, no caso eu só preciso que procure no `select` de estado mesmo, dai deixei `$('select[name=cliente]').each(function () {` mas quando faço isso deveria já ter executado `changeSelect`  mas não chamou, tem ideia de como posso fazer?

Comment: @MarceloDiniz, qual é o select `name=cliente` ? Se é só um não precisa de `each()`

Comment: então, fiz uma atualizado não seu exemplo. Ve se consegue me entender. http://jsfiddle.net/9MWTH/1/

Comment: @MarceloDiniz, chama sim. Adicionei logs ao seu código. Sabe como ver? Deixo também um link de chat aberto se quiser tirar dúvidas. Entretanto veja a consola: http://jsfiddle.net/9MWTH/2/

Comment: Na verdade chama somente quando vc escolhe alguma opção no select de estado, e não nessa chamada automática correto.

Comment: @MarceloDiniz, a linha 2 do seu código é a chamada da função

Comment: Isso mesmo @Sergio. Pq, estou fazendo isso errado?