# Combobox Relacional C# BD Access

Tags: c#, microsoft-access

Estou construindo um aplicação em C# com banco de dados em Access.

Tenho duas tabelas uma de `CIDADE` e outra de `ESTADOS`.

O que necessito é quando for selecionado no `combobox1` um estado, o `combobox2` carregue somente as cidades que correspondem ao estado.

Comment: Olá @Hudson, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. O que já fez até o momento. Pode postar um exemplo de o que você já tentou fazer?

Comment: Possível duplicada de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10697/selecionar-automaticamente-um-select-e-acionar-o-bot%C3%A3o ou http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14646/como-selecionar-uma-op%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-um-select-e-carregar-dados-relacionados-em-outro/14668#14668 ou http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26291/popular-combo-com-chamada-de-ajax

Comment: é que estou iniciando em C#, e até o momento não fiz nada...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sem você passar um trecho de código fica um pouco complicado, mas vou tentar lhe responder de forma que você consiga entender com facilidade, vamos lá...

O seu `combobox1` possui um evento que é executado toda vez que você seleciona um valor (não sei se você está usando Windows Forms ou WPF por isso não posso lhe dizer ao certo o nome do evento). Neste evento você irá programar a rotina que irá carregar as cidades em sua segunda `combobox` (`combobox2`)

Aqui segue uma pergunta similar, talvez lhe ajude:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850932/c-sharp-setting-up-data-bound-cascading-combo-boxes-at-design-time

Você também pode buscar por "Cascading combobox on c#" no Google, com certeza encontrará muitos exemplos e tutoriais.

Abraços.